# Match fixed string part 2

Tags: php, regex

I have this fixed string below.

```
edbe801bf92fe7b770f72df2d722df0a
```

And i match what i need with this regex that someone helped me with and i sort of understand.

```
(?:[^7]*7){4}([^7]*)
```

Now i looked at character class use today but i dont know how to include a number to match a string like this except with `5` or `3` in same position as the string with `7`

How can i also match these numbers and get my text between the last `5` and `3`?

```
edbe801bf92fe5a250e57eb2d522ef0b
edbe801bf92fe3e532b3f0e2f3e0b5fe
```

All should be captured

```
2df2d
7eb2d
f0e2f
```

Comment: Could you please give some examples of what you expect the regex match? It's not clear what exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: The first regex does not match your first example.

Comment: Yes I am not clear on what it is exactly that you are trying to do or whether you really need regex to do it. Can you excplain in plain words what the pattern match is supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to skip the first twenty character and grab the next five, as your sample suggest, you can do it with this simple regular expresion.

```
^.{20}(.{5})
```

This regex give the desired output for all your test lines.

Comment: Even better. Thanks!!